# Use autodividers and count bubbles together in Listview

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I tested the `Autodivider` feature of the JQM `Listview` along with the `Count bubbles`, but i just discovered that they when i set `data-autodivider="true"` the count bubbles disappears:

```js
function setAutodividers() {
  $("#list-1").listview("option", "autodividers", true).listview("refresh");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-mini" onclick="setAutodividers()">Set Autodividers</a>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul id="list-1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Thursday, October 7, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">
            <h2>Avery Walker</h2>
            <p><strong>Re: Dinner Tonight</strong></p>
            <p>Sure, let's plan on meeting at Highland Kitchen at 8:00 tonight. Can't wait!</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:48</strong>PM</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">
            <h2>jQuery Team</h2>
            <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
            <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">
            <h2>Stephen Weber</h2>
            <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
            <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What should i do to have a Listview with autodividers *and* count bubbles?

I just need to display the count of the underlying list items.

Comment: It is an obvious bug. Bubbles are inserted into list-item's header as `span`. When you apply dividers, it overwrites that header.